# Any decent open source link/directory managers out there?

Tags: open-source, directory

I maintain a site with a crusty old version of "Links" by Gossamer Threads.  It's written in perl, gets 99.99% of its submissions from bots, and is just plain out-dated.  Now, I realize that Gossamer has newer versions, but I was hoping to find something that's open source, and maybe in PHP (since 95% of the site's functionality comes from this language).

Does anyone have any opinions on other software to manage a link directory?

Answer (score 1):

Not really exactly what you are looking for but I use http://xmarks.com/ to manage my bookmarks and share them as a RSS feed.

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of some [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/), [Wordpress](http://www.wordpress.org) is pretty much the best option I can think of. It's actively maintained, makes it pretty easy to manage large lists of links in a database (via the 'blogroll' feature), allows people to submit links (with the right plugins), and allows you to secure those submission forms (again, with the right plugins) and to actively police and manage the list.

Comment: I'll certainly keep it in mind, but installing Wordpress for such a relatively simple application seems a bit overkill.

Comment: WP isn't that bad - I've got deployment time down to about an hour, including the server build.

Answer (score 0):

A Freebie that come to mind...

http://www.phplinkdirectory.com - Features a paid version (3.4) but also a free version (2.2 I believe)

PHP & MySQL required.

My own directory utilizes the phplinkdirectory paid version, which will run about 30 bucks, but worth every penny.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Sitebar may meet your needs.

http://sitebar.org/downloads.php